# How to refer each object to a particular object in xtext without user explicitly writing the reference?

Tags: xtext

I am new to xtext framework. Please suggest how to refer each object to a particular object in xtext without user explicitly writing the reference?

For example, each web oject refers to a page as a whole but if user write it in every sentence it looks awkward. Is there anyway to achieve this functionality ?

Comment: Can you be a bit More specific. Maybe you mean the eContainer reference emf has for child to its parent

Comment: I will try to interpret the question above, as I also would interested in such a mechanism. 

Let us take an example similar to the situation above and imagine to have a grammar rule 'Page' containing an 'images' attribute defined as one more rule calls to 'Image'. Let us also suppose 'Image' to have a 'containingPage' attribute. 

How could we define the 'Image' rule so that the 'containingPage' attribute is automatically set as a reference to the current container 'Page' object?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your language doesn't use Xbase, the most likely answer to your problem is to implement a [custom scope provider](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/303_runtime_concepts.html#scoping).